# Angular, not loading Login data

Tags: angular, authentication

In the app there is a top bar that shows a login/logout button depending of the variable isLoggedIn, which receives the data dinamically in app.component.ts from a suscribe as follows:

```
isLoggedIn;
   subscription= this.authService.dataofIsLoggedIn.subscribe(data =>{
    this.isLoggedIn = data;
  });
```

In auth.service.ts, for reference of the previous lines, it reads as follows:

```
isLoggedIn = new BehaviorSubject<string>(this.getToken());
dataofIsLoggedIn = this.isLoggedIn.asObservable();
```

So, I try to display the data in the app.component.html (the top bar) as follows:

```
<div class="VCenterFlex" *ngIf="isLoggedIn">
      <div class="avatarimageContainer_parent">
        <div
          class="avatarimageContainer"
          *ngIf="(authService.currentUser|async)"
          (click)="router.navigate(['/perfil'])"
        >
          <img class="avatarimage" src="{{(authService.currentUser|async)?.avatar}}" />
          <img class="settings_avatar_top" src="../assets/img/settings_icon.png">
        </div>
      </div>

      <h6 style="margin-right: 5px;" *ngIf="(authService.currentUser|async)?.name">
        Hola, {{(authService.currentUser|async).name}}.
      </h6>
      <button
        *ngIf="isLoggedIn"
        (click)="authService.logout()"
        type="button"
        mat-raised-button
        color="accent"
      >
        <mat-icon>exit_to_app</mat-icon> Cerrar sesión
      </button>
    </div>
```

However, once I click log in, the user logs in data-wise, the page redirects to the "main" page, but the top bar is not showing the information. It only shows if I manually refresh the browser.

As @Gérôme Grignon asked, I add the code of auth.service.ts, where currentUser is coded:

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {UserI} from '../models/user';
import {JwtResponseI} from '../models/jwt-response';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import * as moment from "moment";
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class AuthService {
AUTH_SERVER: string = "http://192.168.1.66:3000"; /* "http://localhost:3000"; */
private currentUserSubject: BehaviorSubject<UserI>;
public currentUser: Observable<UserI>;


redirectUrl: string;
private token: string;
isLoggedIn = new BehaviorSubject<string>(this.getToken());
dataofIsLoggedIn = this.isLoggedIn.asObservable();
private expiresin: string;

constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private Router:Router){
  this.currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<UserI>(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')));
  this.currentUser = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();
  this.redirectUrl = "/";
}

checkLogin():boolean{
  var status=false;
  this.dataofIsLoggedIn.subscribe(data =>{
    if (data) {
      status = true;
    }
  });
  if(status){
    return true;
  }
    return false;
}

updateObservableisLoggedIn(tokenstring:string){
  this.isLoggedIn.next(tokenstring);
}

updateObservableUser(user:UserI){
  this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
}

register(user: UserI): Observable<JwtResponseI>{
  return this.httpClient.post<JwtResponseI>(`${this.AUTH_SERVER}/registro`,
  user).pipe(tap(
    (res:JwtResponseI)=>{
      if(res){
        let currentU ={
          name: res.dataUser.name,
          email: res.dataUser.email,
          role: res.dataUser.role,
          id: res.dataUser.id,
          avatar: res.dataUser.avatar,
          signature: res.dataUser.signature
        };
        //guardar token
        this.saveToken(res.dataUser.accessToken, res.dataUser.expiresIn, currentU);
      }
    }
  ));
}

updateUser(user: UserI): Observable<JwtResponseI>{
  return this.httpClient.post<JwtResponseI>(`${this.AUTH_SERVER}/updateuser`,
  user).pipe(tap(
    (res:JwtResponseI)=>{
      if(res){
        let currentU = {
          name: res.dataUser.name,
          email: res.dataUser.email,
          role: res.dataUser.role,
          id: res.dataUser.id,
          avatar: res.dataUser.avatar,
          signature: res.dataUser.signature
        };

        //guardar token
        this.saveToken(res.dataUser.accessToken, res.dataUser.expiresIn, currentU);
      }
    },error =>{console.log(error);},
    () =>{

    }
  ));
}

login(user: UserI): Observable<JwtResponseI>{
  return this.httpClient.post<JwtResponseI>(`${this.AUTH_SERVER}/login`,
  user).pipe(tap(
    (res:JwtResponseI)=>{
      if(res){
        let currentU ={
          name: res.dataUser.name,
          email: res.dataUser.email,
          role: res.dataUser.role,
          id: res.dataUser.id,
          avatar: res.dataUser.avatar,
          signature: res.dataUser.signature
        };
        //guardar token
      this.saveToken(res.dataUser.accessToken, res.dataUser.expiresIn, currentU);
      }
    },error =>{console.log(error);}
  ));
}

public get currentUserValue(): UserI {
  return this.currentUserSubject.value;
}

logout():void {
  this.token="";
  localStorage.removeItem("ACCESS_TOKEN");
  localStorage.removeItem("EXPIRES_IN");
  localStorage.removeItem("currentUser");
  this.updateObservableisLoggedIn(this.token);
  /* let redirect = this.redirectUrl ? this.Router.parseUrl(this.redirectUrl) : "/auth/login"; */
  let redirect = "/success";
  console.log("Logout hace redirect a : "+redirect);
  this.Router.navigateByUrl(redirect);

  /* window.location.reload(); */
}

private saveToken(token:string, expiresIn:string, CurrentUser):void{
  this.updateObservableisLoggedIn(token);
  const expiresAt = moment().add(localStorage.getItem('EXPIRES_IN'),'second');
  localStorage.removeItem("ACCESS_TOKEN");
  localStorage.removeItem("EXPIRES_IN");
  localStorage.removeItem("currentUser");
  localStorage.setItem("ACCESS_TOKEN", token);
  localStorage.setItem("EXPIRES_IN", JSON.stringify(expiresAt.valueOf()));
  this.token = token;
  this.expiresin = JSON.stringify(expiresAt.valueOf());
  localStorage.setItem("currentUser", JSON.stringify(CurrentUser));
  this.token = token;
  this.updateObservableUser(<UserI>CurrentUser);
}

private getToken():string{
  if(!this.token){
    this.token=localStorage.getItem("ACCESS_TOKEN");
  }
  return this.token;
}

private getExpiration(){
  const expiration = localStorage.getItem("EXPIRES_IN");
  const expiresAt = JSON.parse(expiration);
  return moment(expiresAt);
}

}
```

Comment: please add authService.currentUser definition and how its value is changed

Comment: I added the code of auth.service as I thought would be better for someone to check the whole, instead of parts of code. Sorry for the messy code.

Comment: in `saveToken` try add at the end `this.isLoggedIn.next(this.token)` & also add some logs in `updateObservableisLoggedIn` & in `this.authService.dataofIsLoggedIn.subscribe`

Comment: Did this @Shorbagy, the behaviour didn't change.

Comment: I have been checking thoroughly and I find that the problem can be in the declaration isLoggedIn = new BehaviorSubject<string>(this.getToken()); You see, in local storage there IS a ACCESS_TOKEN item. But for some reason, dataOfIsLoggedIn (which is isLoggedIn.asObservable) is not reading it. I do believe the problem is somewhere here, but with my limited knowledge I can't tell what is failing here. @Shorbagy